# Transforming a JSONObject to JSONArray in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, json, kotlin

[Kotlin code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jM6xA.jpg)

```
 private fun loadRecyclerViewData() {

    val request = Request.Builder().url(URL_Json).build()
    val client = OkHttpClient()
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback{

        override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {

            jsonData = response?.body()?.string()

            data class Info( val id: Int, val type: Int, val message: String, val typefield: Any, val hidden: Boolean,
                             val topSpacing: Int, val show: Any, val required: Boolean)
            //val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
            val gson = Gson()
            val persons = gson.fromJson(jsonData, Info::class.java)

            println("mensagem "+ jsonData) //return jsonObject 
            println("mensagem "+ persons)  //return null 

            runOnUiThread {
                //recyclerView?.adapter = FieldAdapter(feed)
            }
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
            println("Fail request")
        }
    })

}
```

JSON link:
https://floating-mountain-50292.herokuapp.com/cells.json

Hi guys.
I need some help with Kotlin. I want to transform a JSONObjetct into JSONArray. But I have return = null.
can you help me?

First Println return JSONObject ok, but second println return null.

println 1
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTdqm.jpg

println 2
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hg9h.jpg

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far?

Comment: How about the `Info` class?

Comment: Also, it's better if you can put the quote into your question instead of screenshots.

Comment: Ok. Edited now.

Comment: Your JSON is an object containing a single property named `cells`. That doesn't match at all with your Info data class.

Comment: Could you help me by showing me how it would look?

Comment: `data class CellInfoList(@SerializedName("cells") val infos : List<Info>)` followed by `val persons = gson.fromJson(jsonData, Info::class.java).infos`